# Facebook description insert new line or return

Tags: facebook, share, meta-tags

simple as it sound, how do i insert a next line or line break or newline, like the 
 or \n in the og:description.

i need this line

```
<meta property="og:description" content="here goes the description. and here goes the next line"/>
```

like this one other

```
<meta property="og:description" content="here goes the description. 
and here goes the next line"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm curious, have you found a solution?

Comment: nop. that;s pretty bad

Comment: 3 years later, and stil without a solution. Good work Fb

Answer (score -1):

This may work.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="here goes the description. \r\n and here goes the next line"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, at least in mine case.
Thanks anyway